# Determining the key of a Vigenere Cipher if key length is known

Tags: cryptography, vigenere

I'm struggling to get my head around the Vigenere Cipher when you know the length of the key but not what it is. I can decipher text if I know the key but I'm confused as to how to work out what the key actually is.

For one example I'm given cipher text and a key length of 6. That's all I'm given, I'm told the key is an arbitrary set of letters that don't necessarily have to make up a word in the english language, in other words, a random set of letters.

With this knowledge I've only so far broken up the cipher text into 6 subtexts, each containing the letters encrypted by the key letters so the first subtext contains every 6th letter starting with the first. The second every 6th letter starting with the second letter and so on.

What do I do now?

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment. You probably won't get details beyond basic advice.

Comment: For the most part it is. I'm looking for a good explanation of next steps , not a solution, just how I can reach a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculate a letter frequency table for each letter of the key. If, as in your example, the key length is 6, you get 6 frequency tables. You should get similar frequencies, although not for the same letters. If you do not, the you have the wrong key length.

Now you check letter frequency tables for English (for example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency). If the pattern does not match, the clear text was not in English. If it does, assign the most frequent letters in each subtext to the most frequent letters in the frequency table etc. and see what you get. You should note that your text may have slightly different frequencies, the reference tables are statistics based on a large amount of data. Now you need to use you head.

Using common digrams (such as th and sh in English) can help.

Answer (score -2):

One approach is frequency analysis. Take each of the six groups and build a frequency table for each character. Then compare that table to a table of known frequencies for the plaintext (if it's standard text, this would just be the English language).

A second, possibly simpler, approach is to just brute-force each character. The number of possible keys is 26^6 ~= 300,000,000, which is about 29 bits of key space. This is brute-forceable but would probably take a bit of time on a personal computer. But if you brute-force one character at a time would only take 26*6 = 156 tries. To do so, write a function that "scores" an attempted decrypted plaintext with how "plaintext-like" it looks. You might do frequency analysis like above, but there can be simpler tests. Then brute-force each of the six sets of characters and pick the key letter that scores the best for decrypting each one of them.